# How can a function only take positive number?

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm new to python and currently learning about error handling in python. There is an exercise that I want to solve but can't figure out how.

> The function receives the value of r and returns the volume of the
> sphere. In the event that a r equal to or less than zero is passed to
> the function, the function returns a notification of incorrect data
> entry.
>
> Protect the function from crashing. In case of exceptions during
> execution, the function must return an error message.

My code

```
import math
def vol(r):
    try:
        return (4/3*math.pi*r**3)           
      
    except TypeError:
        return "A type error has occurred."
```

When I test print(vol(-3)) it gives me -113.09733552923254 as result but it should warn me that number is less than 0.

Comment: Why do you think it should warn you? You don't check the value of r in the implementation.

Comment: Coderunner marks this as an error because the expected output is "
You entered incorrect values." and my code returns the volume of it even if it's 0.

Comment: Check the value of r, if it is negative raise a ValueError exception. check how to raise exception in python

Comment: Right, because your implementation *doesn't* check the value. `r**3` can be calculated for negative values of `r` just fine, even though it doesn't have physical meaning in this case, it won't throw an error.

Comment: The requirement to return an error message is poor design. The *caller* could trap exceptions with `try`/`except` if they should want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it will return a number even if you input the negative value. Because there is no expectation to occur error when you input negative value.

if you want to make it occur the error, use `raise` with `if`

here is example

```py
import math
def vol(r):
    try:
        if r <= 0:
            raise TypeError
        return (4/3*math.pi*r**3)           
      
    except TypeError:
        return "A type error has occurred."
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If you dont want to raise an exception, you can also print out normal error message in the console.

```
import math
def vol(r):
    if(r <= 0):
        raise ValueError("Radius should be greater than 0")
    return (4/3*math.pi*r**3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I'm guessing you must be trying to solve a coding challenge that expects specific outputs given specific inputs.

> expected output is " You entered incorrect values."

> should warn me that number is **less than 0**.

While I think it's better to solve this kind of challenge on your own, here is a possible solution.

```py
import math

def vol(r):
    try:
        # You weren't checking the value of r
        if r < 0:
            raise ValueError

        return (4 / 3 * math.pi * r**3)           
      
    except ValueError:
        # If a ValueError occurs, return the string expected for the challenge
        return ("You entered incorrect values.")
```